# What is a complementary binomial distribution function $\Phi[a; n,p]$?

Tags: pr.probability

I am trying to understand a paper on options titled "OPTION PRICING: A SIMPLIFIED APPROACH" [1]. In it option price is calculated as the expected payoff from the possible states of stock prices by binomial distribution approach.
I am stuck at one step.
What does the following sentences exactly mean?

> Now, the latter bracketed expression is the complementary binomial distribution function $\Phi[a; n,p]$. The first bracketed expression can also be interpreted as a complementary binomial distribution function $\Phi[a; n, p’]$.

Thank you in advance.

**Bibliography**

[1] John C. COX and Stephen A. ROSS and Mark RUBINSTEIN "[Option Pricing: A Simplified Approach](http://static.stevereads.com/papers_to_read/option_pricing_a_simplified_approach.pdf)", Journal of Financial Economics 7 (1979) 229-263. [DOI: 10.1016/0304-405X(79)90015-1](https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-405X(79)90015-1)

Comment: Please take the effort to copy the "bracketed expressions" in your question.

Comment: Hi, the format of expression is not getting pasted properly. I tried attaching image of it also, but it says I don't have sufficient reputation points. Can you please suggest an alternative.

Comment: Thanks Daniele for the edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complementary binomial distribution is defined by
$$\Phi(a;n,p)=\sum _{j=a}^n  \binom{n}{j} p^j(1-p)^{n-j},\;\;0<p<1,\;\;0\leq a\leq n.$$
see [The derivation of diffusion-jump modes for power plant projects under risk](http://www.worldresearchlibrary.org/up_proc/pdf/1124-15114160424-7.pdf). A more correct terminology would be to call $\Phi$ the *complement of the binomial cumulative distribution* function, which is how it is called in [MatLab.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/binocdf.html#mw_d8519302-0c92-417f-88f9-a27b6a3f4e7f)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I will checked it, but it contains same step like the paper I mentioned and I am trying to understand that only. What exactly is complementary binomial distribution function and how this is derived:

Comment: p′ = (u/r)p and 1 – p′ = (d/r)(1 – p)

Comment: 1) $\Phi(a;n,p)$ is the probability that the binomial random variable takes a value in the range $a,a+1,\ldots n$.

Comment: 2) the cited paper contains two instances of $\Phi$, one instance with probability $p$ (which is the formula I wrote down), and one instance with a different probability $p'=(u/r)p$; then $1-p'=(d/r)(1-p)$ for $d=(r-pu)/(1-p)$.

Comment: Hi, "Φ(a;n,p) is the probability that the binomial random variable takes a value in the range a,a+1,…n", it means it's complementary probability distribution function as per the MatLab site you posted right?